# Upgrading Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: 13.10, upgrade

My desktop is currently installed with Ubuntu 13.10, I have downloaded 14.04.1 LTS software.I have 2 questions
1. Is any method to upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04
2. Is I have to do a clean install, if clean install, is my data in Ubuntu 13.10 will be erased.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can go from Ubuntu 13.10 to 1.04.1 LTS, you can either upgrade using the 'Software Updater' and no data will be lost or you can do a clean install. I recommend doing a clean install but make sure you backup any important data as it will be deleted if you do decide to go with a clean install. Also Ubuntu 14.10 came out yesterday so you may want to consider jumping straight to it, so far it's been rock solid.

Upgrade from a previous version of Ubuntu
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

Using a USB or CD/DVD
DVD: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu
USB: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu